# Add 1 new row for each row and then update all the records, but Why it JUST Update 1 / 2 records of Gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview

I add 1 new row for each row in a GridView and then update all the records, but it only updates 1 / 2 records of GridView? Can anybody help me?

This is my code:
1, Add new row for or each row in GridView

```
protected void gvUsersL_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 
        GridViewRow g = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        //creating table Cells
        TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
        tCell.Text = table;

        //Add Cells
        g.Cells.Add(tCell);
        tCell.ColumnSpan = e.Row.Cells.Count;

        //Set Color for Empty Cell
        g.CssClass = "bgi_1";
        Table tbl = e.Row.Parent as Table;

        //add rows
        tbl.Rows.Add(g);
    }
}
```

2, Then Update:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvUsersL.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //update here
}
```

Can any body help me? Thanks.

Comment: Adding rows on `RowDataBound` sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Their's a method in C# for datagrid named update.

```
gvUsersL.update();
```

Not shure if this is what you acutally want but this method update you're datagrid according to the linked data.

Comment: Thank you PRacicot, But it Just Update 1/2 records the first of the Girdview, It Not Update 1/2 records the last of Girdview. have you any ideas give for me ? Thanks your help

Comment: when you say update, you mean insert data or update the records with the datasource?